# c++ type conversion: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HRESULT' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'

Tags: c++

I tried this in Visual studios 2012:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
std::wstring applicationdatafolder = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath);
MessageBox(NULL, applicationdatafolder, NULL, MB_OK);
```

I got those errors:

Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'HRESULT' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'    (2nd row)

Error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::wstring' to 'LPCWSTR'    (3rd row)

Answer (score 3):

the `SHGetFolderPath` function do return a `HRESULT` to show if everything went right. The actual "string" will be stored where last parameter points to: ergo into `szPath`.
Now what you want is to construct the string from this char array via `std::wstring applicationdatafolder (szPath)` and use it

**addendum for Qs emerged in comments**

`wstring foo(bar)` vs `wstring foo = bar`
afaik (feel free to edit if im wrong) the usage of the copy constructor is more efficient:

`wstring foo(bar)`

1. creates a new wstring but knows what will be stored
2. allocates enough memory for content from `bar`
3. copies content from `bar`

`wstring foo = bar` is essentialy `wstring foo(); foo = bar;`

1. creates a new **empty** wstring (`wstring foo` calls the default constructor without params)
2. allocates 1 byte (only line ending symbol will be stored)
3. places the line ending there
4. calls `operator=`
5. frees the memory allocated in 2.
6. allocates enough place to store content from `bar`
7. copies the content from `bar`

of course the compiler will probably recognize the redundant steps and optimize the code, but by using the former version we write efficient code in first place and don't rely on compiler optimiziation

also the former version is somewhat clearer as it reads as "make a `wstring` named `foo` from `bar`" and latter is "make a `wstring` named `foo` and assign `bar` to it". Pay attention to the fakt `bar` can be of some arbitrary type and though compiler understands what you want, it may seem look strange to have a `string` and some `mywierdtype` in an assignment.

Comment: c++ syntax feels a bit confusing for me... 'applicationdatafolder' does not look like a function. How does the passing of 'szPath' work when 'applicationdatafolder' is not a function?

Comment: `someType myVariable(someStuff)` will call the **constructor** of `someType`.

Comment: How does 'applicationdatafolder' process 'szPath'? What does it actually do with 'szPath'?

Comment: @user2726531 applicationdatafolder is a variable of type std::wstring, and you can see it initialized also. You need to learn a lot man.

Comment: @user2726531 you might really want to learn the language basics first, experiment with structs and classes, look into `std`. Sure console stuff may not seem impressive and satisfactory like a cool GUI program, but i made same mistake by starting GUI first and it wasted 3 years of my time. Starting `c++` from `winapi` is like learning horology by poking in your watch instead of learning what those spiky wheels do :) also check updated answser

Answer (score 1):

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath);
std::wstring applicationdatafolder(szPath);
MessageBox(NULL, applicationdatafolder.c_str(), NULL, MB_OK);
```

Comment: What is the idea behind this in C++ syntax: "std::wstring applicationdatafolder(szPath)"

Comment: It's a constructor with a parameter

Comment: How does 'applicationdatafolder' process 'szPath'? What does it actually do with 'szPath'?

Comment: Is there any benefit of using that construction instead of: std::wstring applicationdatafolder= szPath;

Comment: @user2726531 Copy constructor versus operator=. Read about these.